# in java, equivalent to date(String) method?

Tags: java, datetime

I want to get the difference between two times.  I.e., current time and time1 (like `"17 Jun 2011 01:59:25"`). By one way, we can do by using `Date(string)`. But it is deprecated method.  How to do this with a non-deprecated method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` to parse a string into a `Date` object. For example:

```
String text = "17 Jun 2011 01:59:25";

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date date = df.parse(text);
```

You can get the time difference between two `Date` objects by calling `getTime()` on them and subtracting the values:

```
Date now = new Date();
long diff = now.getTime() - date.getTime();

System.out.println("Time difference in milliseconds: " + diff);
```

If you want to know the difference in seconds, minutes, hours, etc. then divide the number of milliseconds by the appropriate factor.

Answer (score 2):

There is comment on deprecated tag

```
replaced by DateFormat.parse(String s)
```